# HTML5 Server-Sent Events not real time?

Tags: javascript, php, html, server-sent-events

My code is supposed to send one event each second from the server to the client (I should see them coming at regular intervals in the Firefox's console). But I get all five events at once. Why?

adm.php:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type='text/javascript'>
var evtSource;
function btnClick() {
    evtSource = new EventSource('adm_sse.php');
    evtSource.onmessage = function(e) {
        console.log(e.data);
        if (e.data == 'end') {
            evtSource.close();
        }
    };
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <button type='button' onclick='btnClick()'>Test SSE</button>
</body>
</html>
```

adm_sse.php:

```
<?php
header("Content-Type: text/event-stream");
//header('Cache-Control: no-cache'); // recommended to prevent caching of event data.
for ($i=0; $i<5; $i++) {
    echo "data: $i (".date('d/m/Y H:i:s').")\n\n";
    flush();
    sleep(1);
}
echo "data:end\n\n";
flush();
?>
```

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 with Apache, if that matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an [example in the MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Server-sent_events/Using_server-sent_events) which uses php code similar to yours with one small difference, it is calling [`ob_end_flush()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-end-flush.php).

Comment: Thanks! Seems that I need to use both, ob_end_flush() followed by flush()... strange...

Comment: not doing php for long, are you ;)
glad to see it work.

Comment: Yeah, not so long... but enough to see such weird things and start thinking it's _normal_...